# How do I enable phpMyAdmin's Designer view? in phpmyadmin 4.6

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

i cant enable designer view in phpmyadmin 4.6 ... i searching about enable designer in phpmyadmin but just found some posts about phpmyadmin 4.0.7 or 4.5 !
phpmyadmin 4.6 is different
i haven't create_tables.sql file in examples directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phpMyAdmin installation should have come with documentation specific to your version, try the ./doc/ or ./doc/html/ folder.

For several versions now, the create_tables.sql file exists in the ./sql/ folder.

You can see the complete directions for the current development version at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration, but the basic jist is to create a 'controluser' using the provided SQL query and your own password (the SQL query can vary depending on phpMyAdmin version but is currently

> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON .* TO 'pma'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';

Once you've done that, import the contents of `sql/create_tables.sql`, editing it first if you need to. You can use phpMyAdmin or the command-line client to perform this import.

Finally, edit `config.inc.php` and set the database name, table names, and controluser/controlpass.

Once you have properly configured the phpMyAdmin configuration storage, you should see "Designer" as a menu tab from the database-level pages (not from a table-level page, though).